# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element error finding an element using Xpath Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Here is the element I am trying to click on for an automated program using Selenium:

```
<input id="btnNextWeek" title="Next Week" onclick="if (this.className != 'mybtndis2') { moveweek(7) }" type="button" value=">>" name="btnNextWeek" class="mybtn2" style="-webkit-appearance: button; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px; height: auto">
```

Getting this error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@title="Next Week"]"} (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

This is the code that gives the error:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title=\"Next Week\"]")\
.click()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider using code fences for the elements and responses. This will make your question a lot more readable. This can be accomplished easily by selecting text and clicking the associated buttons on top in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use this - driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@title="Next Week"]').click()

This will work.Always if you are using double quotes inside use single quote before to get rid of the escaping and we dont need to escape the . before click() because here . is used to call a method.

Thanks.

Comment: This didn't work, but thank you for the tip regarding single quotes!

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.mybtn2#btnNextWeek[title='Next Week'][name='btnNextWeek']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='mybtn2' and @id='btnNextWeek'][@title='Next Week' and @name='btnNextWeek']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on *no such element* in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Didn't work for some reason. Just timing out after 20 seconds. Appreciate you trying to help though!

Answer (score 0):

It could be the element cannot be found because it is inside an iframe... if so then you could use

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('insert frame xpath')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@title="Next Week"]').click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```